# mixing float-span() and grid-span() in same context?

Tags: sass, singularitygs

ahoy all,

i have a simple example that mixes `float-span` and `grid-span` mixins within the same grid context (i.e. the same number of columns in the same row)

http://sassbin.com/gist/7812502/

as you can see, i have 3 items that i want to space out evenly in a row.  i use `float-span` with `first` and `last` options on items 1 and 3 to make them sit at the beginning and end of the row respectively, and this works as expected.  for the middle item, which i want centered, i assumed i could use `grid-span` with the correct location to have the 2nd item in the middle.  however, what is happening is that the counting of location for `grid-span` is started *after* the column taken up by the first floated item.  is this expected behavior?  in other words, is it allowable to mix `float-span` and `grid-span` in the same grid context/row?  and if not, what is the preferred way in Singularity for accomplishing the same thing?

i have been searching the documentation wiki, in particular the section on [spanning the grid](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid), but have found no statements either way.  and the demos do not seem to be using `float-span` and `grid-span` together.

thanks as usual for Singularity and for any help.

peace

PS. i have already tried using the `isolation-span` mixin in place of `grid-span` with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to mix output styles like float and isolation in the same grid. You should pick either isolation or floats and stick with it.

Here is your sassbin tweaked a bit: http://sassbin.com/gist/7815953/

Comment: thanks for confirming that.  also, it was interesting to see that `grid-span` can accept 'last' for the `$location` parameter (i see that the `end-row` function handles that input). unfortunately 'first' is not valid as a '$location` for grid-span. is there a reason why?  thanks again, Singularity is great to work with.